# Uploading alternate rows of Pixel Data OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am uploading an interlaced image to an OpenGL texture using glTexImage2D which of course uploads whole image. What I need is to upload only alternate rows, so on first texture odd rows and on second even rows.

I don't want to create another copy of the Pixel Data on CPU.

Comment: When you say _"on first texture odd rows and on second even rows"_ are you talking about two different textures? I thought you meant you wanted to create a single texture but upload the data using two images (one image stores the odd scanlines and the other stores even), but judging by Reto Koradi's answer I may have misinterpreted that.

Comment: It can be 2 textures or 2 rendering passes.

Comment: I mean, do you want to store the result in one texture or two textures? The first sentence implies that you want a single deinterlaced texture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` to twice the actual row length. This will effectively skip every second row. If the size of your texture is `width` x `height`:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 2 * width);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, width);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
```

Instead of setting `GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS` to skip the first row, you can also increment the data pointer accordingly.

Comment: Will the resulting texture be half the hight of the original image?

Comment: Yes. In the above, `height` is the height of the resulting textures. The original image will have to be twice that height.

Answer (score 3):

There is [an ancient SGI extension (`GL_SGIX_interlace`)](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/SGIX/interlace.txt) for transferring interlaced pixel data, but it is probably not supported on your implementation.

An alternative you might consider is memory mapping a Pixel Buffer Object. You can fill this buffer over two passes and then use it as the source of image data in a call to `glTexImage2D (...)`. You essentially do the de-interlacing yourself, but since this is done by mapping a buffer object's memory you are not making an unnecessary copy of the image on the CPU.

#### Pseudo code showing how to do this:

```c
GLuint deinterlace_pbo;
glGenBuffers (1, &deinterlace_pbo);

// `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`, when non-zero is the source of memory for `glTexImage2D`
glBindBuffer (GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, deinterlace_pbo);

// Reserve memory for the de-interlaced image
glBufferData (GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, sizeof (pixel) * interlaced_rows * width * 2,
              NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Returns a pointer to the ***GL-managed memory*** where you will write the image
void* pixel_data = glMapBuffer (GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);

// Odd Rows First
for (int i = 0; i < interlaced_rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    //Fill in pixel_data for each pixel in row (i*2+1)
  }
}

// Even Rows
for (int i = 0; i < interlaced_rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    //Fill in pixel_data for each pixel in row (i*2)
  }
}

glUnmapBuffer ();

// This will read the memory in the object bound to `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`
glTexImage2D (..., NULL);
glBindBuffer (GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
```